# Update view after subview change SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have a `Show` `CoreData` `NSManagedObject` with multiple `Seasons`. Both models can be marked as `watched`. When all seasons of a `Show` are marked as watched the `Show` should be marked watched as well. How do I achieve this? I tried using manual getter and setter for my `NSManagedObject` classes but I can't get my view to update when the state changes.

The GUI:
[image]

My code of the main View:

```
// ShowDetailView.swift

@ObservedObject var show: Show

// ... in the body

Button(action: {
    show.isWatched.toggle()
}, label: {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: show.isWatched ? "checkmark.rectangle.fill" : "checkmark.rectangle")
    }
})

ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    LazyHStack {
        ForEach(seasons) { season in
            NavigationLink(destination: SeasonDetailView(season: season)) {
                SeasonListItemView(season: season)
                    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, viewContext)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The class for the list item:

```
// SeasonListItemView.swift

@ObservedObject var season: Season

Button(action: {
    season.isWatched.toggle()
}, label: {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: season.isWatched ? "checkmark.rectangle.fill" : "checkmark.rectangle")
    }
})
```

I mean it totally makes sense because the `Show` model does not know it should be marked as watched when all seasons are watched, but how can I implemented and let it update automatically and using `CoreData` at the same time?

**// Edit:**
Added my last edit as answer because no other solution was found.

Comment: I was hoping someone would answer this as I am dealing with a similar problem. I think maybe setting up an observer might work, but I’ve never set one up, so I’m not sure.

Comment: @Ethan maybe the edit I did helps you. At least that fixes it for me, but it still feels a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I have managed to fix it with an own setter method on the Season model that checks all seasons on its own show and then sets the flag accordingly, but it doesn't feel really "reactive":

// Manual setter on the Season model

```
func setIsWatched(_ isWatched: Bool) {
    self.isWatched = isWatched

    if let seasons = show?.seasons?.array as? [Season] {
        for season in seasons {
            if !season.isWatched {
                show?.isWatched = false
                return
            }

            show?.isWatched = true
        }
    }
}
```